# about the post_save signal and created argument

Tags: python, django, django-signals

the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) says:

```
post_save
django.db.models.signals.post_save

created
A boolean; True if a -new- record was create.
```

and I have this:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
def handle_new_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print "--------> save() "+str(created)
post_save.connect(handle_new_user, sender=User)
```

when I do in shell:

```
u = User(username="cat")
u.save()
>>> --------> save() True
u.username = "dog"
u.save()
>>> --------> save() True
```

I expect a `>>> --------> save() False` when I save() the second time because is an update? not?

Comment: What version of Django are you using?  When I use the exact same code on 1.1, it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have implemented your own User which doesn't have a unique constraint on username?

Comment: Im implementing "from django.contrib.auth.models import User"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `User.objects.create_user` to avoid bulk operation.